# How to find each sum of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to find sum of each array.

```
(1..9).to_a.combination(3).to_a.each{ |item| item.inject{:+}}
```

But my code gives the followings.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 9], 
[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], ...
```

What I am expecting is something like this.

```
[6, 7, 8, 9,...]
```

How can I find sum of each array?

Comment: if you are using rails then you can use `sum` method like `(1..9).to_a.combination(3).map{|a| a.sum(0)}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are very close, a little change on your code may help:

```
(1..9).to_a.combination(3).map { |a| a.inject(:+) }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
(1..9).to_a.combination(3).to_a.map { |item| item.inject(:+) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way with `#reduce`.

```
(1..9).to_a.combination(3).map { |item| item.reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: `reduce` is an alias for `inject`, but I prefer it in this case.